# How to pass List as parameter from handlers

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

My question is about the fromPublisher method.
I try sende from handlers a list as paramter to my service.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> save(final ServerRequest request) {
    final Flux<Products> products = request.bodyToFlux(Products.class);
    return ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(fromPublisher(((service::save)), List.class));
```

And in my serivce i have:

```
@Override
public Flux<Products> save(List<Products> products) {
    System.out.println(products);
    return repository.saveAll(products);
}
```

}

How i pass the products Flux as List to my service.  It's possible make with reactive controllers?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to?  The whole purpose of using reactive service is to stream objects.  If you want to return normal list, you can just use normal REST API with Spring.

Comment: repository.saveAll() has an implementation that takes a `Flux` as the parameter. There is no need to convert the `Flux` to a `List` in this example.